# Prove that $1^3 + 2^3 + \cdots+n^3$ is $O(n^4)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I suppose I am not exactly familiar with the process for finding the "Big-O" of this problem. Isn't the highest term still to the 3rd degree? $(n^3)$ which would make me think that it is $O(n^3)$, since that seems to be the upper bound...?

Comment: Maybe use the fact that the sum $1^3 + 2^3 + .... + n^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$ and then apply the definition to that function

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? Most of us here would like to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 11):

We have
$$ 1^3 + 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 = \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 \le \sum_{i=1}^n n^3 = n \cdot n^3 = n^4 $$
for all $n$. Hence, $\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 \in O(n^4)$.

Comment: By this logic, wouldn't you also conclude $1+2+\cdots+n=O(n^4)$, because $\sum_{i=1}^n i\leq\sum_{i=1}^n n^3=n^4$?

Comment: Of course, since this is true, as $\frac{n(n+1)}2 \in O(n^4)$.

Comment: OK thanks for the clarification.